# google cloud gcloud app deploy gives me permission denied

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I can't deploy an app anymore. I was able to yesterday, then I deleted the project, then today I re-enabled it. And now when I deploy with `gcloud app deploy` I get a build error, in the build error log I get the following

```
Pulling image: gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00
python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder
Digest: sha256:64993f54d3c409dd342d23167eb3ff5b92485a4225dc30762125e9c99fcf105a
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00
11 May 2019 22:00:03 INFO     Arguments: ['--parser_script=/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--name=eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:248e94c0-9e01-412c-9435-8fc7b0cbda1f', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--entrypoint-from-app-yaml=false', '--entrypoint-contents=', '--base=gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00']
11 May 2019 22:00:03 INFO     Unparsed arguments: ['--name=eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:248e94c0-9e01-412c-9435-8fc7b0cbda1f', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00']
11 May 2019 22:00:03 INFO     Using entrypoint from command line
11 May 2019 22:00:03 INFO     Entrypoint: {'type': 'default'}
11 May 2019 22:00:03 INFO     Executing ['/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--name=eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:248e94c0-9e01-412c-9435-8fc7b0cbda1f', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00', '--entrypoint=/start', '--directory=/workspace', '--additional-directory=/.gaeconfig']
INFO     FTL version python-v0.15.0
INFO     Beginning FTL build for python
INFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_dir /env
INFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168
INFO     FTL arg passed: python_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache True
INFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_cmd virtualenv
INFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint /start
INFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None
INFO     FTL arg passed: pip_cmd /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip
INFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None
INFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path /builder/outputs
INFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv
INFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False
INFO     FTL arg passed: base gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.15.0
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt 
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d
INFO     FTL arg passed: venv_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env
INFO     FTL arg passed: name eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:248e94c0-9e01-412c-9435-8fc7b0cbda1f
INFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False
INFO     FTL arg passed: upload True
INFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True
INFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None
INFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace
INFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.gaeconfig
INFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity DEBUG
INFO     starting: full build
INFO     starting: builder initialization
INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20190328_3_7_3_RC00'
INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:248e94c0-9e01-412c-9435-8fc7b0cbda1f'
INFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds
INFO     starting: build process for FTL image
INFO     starting: checking_cached_interpreter_layer
INFO     starting: check python version
INFO     `python version` full cmd:
/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version
INFO     `python version` stderr:

INFO     check python version took 0 seconds
DEBUG    Checking cache for cache_key d62f0bca0db2e6b2b1312f303e883b8ff187274fe5fd7b9aa17b13cdb68bad80
INFO     checking_cached_interpreter_layer took 0 seconds
INFO     build process for FTL image took 0 seconds
INFO     full build took 0 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 54, in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/builder.py", line 73, in Build
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 361, in BuildLayer
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 113, in Get
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 137, in _getEntry
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 152, in _getLocalEntry
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 175, in getEntryFromCreds
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_image_.py", line 279, in exists
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_image_.py", line 293, in manifest
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_image_.py", line 250, in _content
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_http_.py", line 364, in Request
containerregistry.client.v2_2.docker_http_.V2DiagnosticException: response: {'status': '403', 'content-length': '294', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'Docker Registry', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'docker-distribution-api-version': 'registry/2.0', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sat, 11 May 2019 22:00:04 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
Permission denied for "d62f0bca0db2e6b2b1312f303e883b8ff187274fe5fd7b9aa17b13cdb68bad80" from request "/v2/ellipticdata-ai/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/python-cache/manifests/d62f0bca0db2e6b2b1312f303e883b8ff187274fe5fd7b9aa17b13cdb68bad80". : None
```

I tried to create my credentials from scratch again but no luck, i cant deploy my app anymore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. I need to re enable billing for the project through the 'identity platform'. As apparently the previous approval gets deleted.